# Plot a curve with a list of data

Tags: plotting, functions

I have a list of [data](https://www.mediafire.com/file/4c19ubvle85op3e/test.dat/file) in this form `{{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...,{xn,yn}}`, which can be plotted simply with

```
test = Get["~\\test.dat"];
ListLinePlot[test, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0.35, 0.85}}, Frame -> True]
```

The list can be considered a function $y=y(x)$. Now, I want to plot a curve of $f(x)=y(x)+x\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Because there exists a derivation, I first tried `Interpolation` to make a function `y`.

```
dep = test[[All, 2]]; indep = test[[All, 1]];

y = Interpolation[dep,indep];
```

Then I construct the function and plot it, but it does not work...

```
f = dep + indep*D[y,indep]

Plot[f, {indep, 0, 10}, Frame -> True]
```

My problem should be simple, but I cannot figure out how to fix it. I think the issue may be the `Interpolation` step because I even cannot plot the function itself using the interpolation.

```
Plot[y, {indep, 0, 10}, Frame -> True]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = First@ReadList["C:/test.dat"];
minmax = MinMax[data];
y = Interpolation[data];


p1 = ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> {-0.5, 1.0}];
p2 = Plot[y[x], {x, Splice@minmax}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   PlotRange -> {-0.5, 1.0}];
p3 = Plot[y'[x], {x, Splice@minmax}, PlotStyle -> Darker@Green, 
   PlotRange -> {-0.5, 1.0}];
p4 = Plot[y[x] + x y'[x], {x, Splice@minmax}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> {-0.5, 1.0}]

Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

**EDIT**

If you cannot use `Splice` due to an older version being in use, then use `Sequence @@` as shown below:

```
p4 = Plot[y[x] + x y'[x], {x, Sequence @@ minmax}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotRange -> {-0.5, 1.0}];
```

To find the minimum point:

```
FindMinimum[y[x] + x y'[x], x]
```

> `{0.319033, {x -> 1.1225}}`

---

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Syed, your method basically works, but `Splice` function is removed after v.10. Could you modify the answer with another function that is available in later versions? Btw, may I ask a further question: is there a method to show also the min. value point of `p4` plot by finding where its derivation is zero? I tried `NSolve[2*y'[x]+x y''[x]==0,x]` but does not work. Thank you!

Comment: I have updated my answer.